# Error en hosting con css y bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Hola alguien me puede asesorar hacer del origen y como puedo solucionar el siguiente:

> Error en mi hosting -> El recurso de “https:// misitio000webhostapp.com/css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css” se bloqueó debido a la falta de coincidencia del tipo MIME (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Solo me ocurre con los archivos de bootstrap que están de manera local dentro del proyecto

Comment: Los ficheros css que te dan problema, ¿están añadidos con el path correcto a su ubicación?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder si <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >

Comment: hola, en que servidor está montada tu aplicación? apache iis o que servidor?

Comment: Hola es apache, pero ya lo solucione resulto que tuve que agregar los permisos a los archivos y a las carpetas. Gracias